# Bootstrap, flex-row with small devices

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, internet-explorer, flexbox

I have a strange problem with `flex-row` in bootstrap. I am using the following `css`-setting, copied from the internet:

```
@media only screen and (min-width : 768px) {
   .flex-row.row {
     display: flex;
     flex-wrap: wrap;
   }
   .flex-row.row > [class*='col-'] {
     display: flex;
     flex-direction: column;
   }
}
```

This works perfectly well. The grid boxes are perfectly located next to each other and no strange break is made.

Some day I recognized the setting `min-width: 768px`. As I wanted grid boxes next to each other for small devices as well, I changed it to `0px`. This worked perfectly well, when I minimized my internet browser (firefox and chrome) on my laptop to simulate mobile phone behaviour.

Now the problem: I opened the website with my smartphone (some IE on a Windows Phone) and the structure was totally broke. I played around with the settings but the only stable possibility is to have all the content for mobile phones one below the other (e.g. `col-xs-12`) and switch back to `min-width: 768px`.

This doesn't satisfy me. Where is the problem? Or is it a specific problem with my device as it worked well with the minimized internet browser on my laptop?

Comment: Which version does your Windows phone's IE have?

Comment: I have Windows Phone 8.1 ...

Comment: Since `flexbox` has issues on that version and it works in your browser, I would consider this a _device problem_: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn736066(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Try another small device like a iOS/Android smart phone/tablet ... just make sure they support non prefixed `flexbox`

Comment: Hmm, not nice. I will try it with IOS and Android as far as I can and I will report ...